# Meteor JS global function

Tags: javascript, function, meteor, module-pattern

using Meteor.js I want to use a global function which contains other functions :

```
BIG = function (){

     this.init = function ()
     {
        //do something
     }

     this.addSomething = function (param1, param2)
     {
        //do something else
     }

}
```

Now im calling this functions like :

```
 BIG.init();
 BIG.addSomething(param1, param2);
```

But this is not working, the console print "BIG.init is not a function".
When i type "BIG" in my console it print back "function BIG()" which means Meteor recognize that BIG is a function but does'nt recognize the subfunctions inside BIG.

Any help on how can i achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax, should be this (according to your current syntax):

```
new BIG().init();
new BIG().addSomething();
```

You see, you need construct a `new BIG` instance using the `new` keyword to properly set the `this` context inside of `BIG`, then it will return it's methods for you to execute.

But I doubt that's actually what you are trying to do. Are you sure you don't just want to declare an object literal like below:

```
BIG = {

     init: function ()
     {
        //do something
     }

     addSomething: function (param1, param2)
     {
        //do something else
     }

}
BIG.init();
BIG.addSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use object returning by this function?
I.e.:

```
var big = function() {

    return {
        init: function() {
            alert(1);
        },

        addSomething: function(param1, param2) {
            //do something else
        }
    }
}

BIG = big();

BIG.init();
```